# How to call javascript function if form invalid in Symfony

Tags: javascript, validation, forms, symfony1

I would like to call a javascript function in Symfony after I validate the form, and it was invalid. Where can I call this function?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to make the call from your view. How exactly you want to do that depends on what youre trying to achieve.

For example:

```
public function executeFormSubmitAction(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    $this->form = new MyForm();
    $this->form->bind($request->getParamter($$this->form->getName());
    $this->valid = null;

    if($this->form->isValid())
    {
       // do stuff with values

       $this->valid = true;
    }
    else
    {
       $this->valid = false;
    }
}
```

And then in your view:

```
<?php if($valid === true): ?>
  Thanks!
<?php else: ?>
  <?php echo $form; ?>
  <?php if(false === $valid): ?>
    <!-- your javascript call and related stuff -->
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

IF there is an entirely different structure for the views of each condition for `$valid` then you might want to use actuall put all that in partials and then use `include_partial` inside the conditions, or you could use seperate view templates and use `setTemplate` in your action to render the correct one... Or if they are really complex and require special logic you could use `forward` and seperate actions entirely. Or if this is an ajax submission you could return json instead of html and then execute your js function as part of the callback - checking the returned json for a variable flagging the result of validation.

Its really up to you.